# IntelliJ suggests 'replace()' could be replaced by compiled java.util.regex.Pattern construct

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

One particular IntelliJ IDEA inspection gets triggered when I have code like:

```
string1 = string2.replace(string3, string4);
```

The inspection says:

> 'replace()' could be replaced by compiled java.util.regex.Pattern construct.

And then offers to refactor the code for me, which results in using a constant literal Pattern.

I have this inspection turned on mainly for cases where I'm actually creating a regex dynamically. It can sometimes improve performance if I follow IntelliJ's suggestion. But in the case of `String.replace()` the argument is not a regex. Is it true that following IntelliJ's suggestion in this case would not result in any performance improvement at all, and all it would do is hurt readability?

Is it possible to turn it off for `String.replace()` but keep it on for `String.replaceAll()` and `String.replaceFirst()`? I couldn't see such an option.

Comment: If you look at the implementation of `String.replace(String, String)`, you'll see why it's recommending using an explicit `Pattern` ;)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Beat me to it. `return Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(…`

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth / @jensgram, where do you see the method signature `String.replace(String, String)`? I am referring to [JDK8 api docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), and there's only `replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` and from its implementation, it does not `return Pattern.compileXXX`.

Comment: @jumping_monkey the [JDK 1.8 source](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk8-b120/jdk/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L2225) does indeed call `Pattern.compile`, but later versions don't use Pattern at all (for example [jdk11](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-11%2B28/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L2141)). Therefore the accepted answer only applies to jdk8 but not later versions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @KlitosKyriacou. I found the exact commit for the change [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/f35750c5d63f5df4d31322b372e25c01696028df). Cheers mate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation<sup>1</sup> of `String.replace(String, String)` simply delegates to `Pattern.compile(...).matcher(...).replaceAll(...)`.  So I can't imagine a situation where using an explicit `Pattern` in user code would be **less** performant (indeed, in many cases it's likely to end up **more** performant).  Readability is, of course, a different question!

I'm not sure it's possible to configure the IntelliJ inspection, but you can [suppress it](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/suppressing-inspections.html) for individual statements, methods, or classes.

---

<sub>1. At least in Oracle's JDK8.</sub>

Comment: If you use `replace` in a loop, you could move `Pattern.compile(..)` outside the loop to make it more performant.

Comment: @marstran - Absolutely.  But I'm saying that I don't think one could make code *less* performant by using a pattern.  I've tweaked my answer to point out that one may end up with more performant code in many scenarios, though.

Comment: For readers using more recent JDK versions: this answer is true only for JDK8. From JDK11 onwards, `String.replace` does not use `Pattern` at all.